# Cant perform Paste function in C# WPF using Deserialize method

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

So I'm currently working on a "Paint" similar application and I wanna copy a selected item and perform "copy" and "Paste" function to it but it seems I'm having some trouble. I'm using Serialize and Deserialize method to work on it. The following shows some of the key codes:

The following is for Serialize Method:

```
public XElement Serialize()
    {
        RotateTransform contentRotate = this.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
        double rotateAngle = 0;

        string savedItem = XamlWriter.Save(this.Content); //Null?

        if (contentRotate != null)
        {
            rotateAngle = contentRotate.Angle;
        }

        XElement serial = new XElement("DesignerItem",
                          new XAttribute("Width", this.Width),
                          new XAttribute("Height", this.Height),
                          new XAttribute("Name", this.Name),
                          new XAttribute("RotateAngle", rotateAngle),
                          new XAttribute("Left", Canvas.GetLeft(this)),
                          new XAttribute("Top", Canvas.GetTop(this)),
                          new XAttribute("Offset", 0),
                          new XAttribute("Content", savedItem));
        return serial;
    }//End of Serialize
```

The following is the Deserialize method:

```
public static DesignerItem Deserialize(XElement serial)
    {
        DesignerItem item = new DesignerItem();

        item.Width = Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Width").Value);
        item.Height = Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Width").Value);
        item.Name = serial.Attribute("Name").Value;
        Canvas.SetLeft(item, Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Left").Value) + Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Offset").Value));
        Canvas.SetTop(item, Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Top").Value) + Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("Offset").Value));
        /*This part is for the "Content"*/
        var value = serial.Element("Content").Value; //NullReferenceException Occurred
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(value);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        ContentElement readerLoad = (ContentElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        item.Content = readerLoad;

        item.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        item.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(Double.Parse(serial.Attribute("RotateAngle").Value));

        return item;
    }//End of Deserialize
```

The following is for CopySelection method:

```
private void copySelection()
    { 
        XElement serial = this.SelectedItem.Serialize();
        serial.SetAttributeValue("OffSet", 15);
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Xaml, serial);
    }//End of copySelection
```

The following is for the Paste command:

```
private void Paste_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Xaml))
        {
            string clipboardData = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Xaml) as string;

            if (clipboardData != null && clipboardData != string.Empty)
            {
                this.CreateRestorePoint();

                XElement serial = XElement.Load(new StringReader(clipboardData));
                DesignerItem item = DesignerItem.Deserialize(serial);
                this.Children.Add(item);
                this.SelectedItem = item;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Paste_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Xaml);
    }
```

A NullReferenceException error occurred on the Deserialize Method:

```
var value = serial.Element("Content").Value;
```

I understand that the error is due to Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Thus, after much-reversed engineering, I've noticed that the "Object Reference" it meant was the "Content". 
So, here is my question. When I traced back to the Serialize method:

```
string savedItem = XamlWriter.Save(this.Content);
```

Does "Save(this.Content)" <-- consider empty? 
When I run it the whole project no error happened till the moment I clicked on my "Paste" button. Deeply appreciated if there's anyone out there that can assist my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I found out my mistakes.
Since in my Deserialize Method wanted to call "serial.**Element**("Content")".

```
var value = serial.Element("Content").Value;
```

In the Serialize Method, the Content part is supposed to be **XElement**, not *XAttribute*.
Thus, change this line:

```
new XAttribute("Content", savedItem);
```

to this line:

```
new XElement("Content", savedItem);
```

**Furthermore**, for the "Content part" in Deserialize Method:

```
var value = serial.Element("Content").Value; //NullReferenceException Occurred
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(value);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
ContentElement readerLoad = (ContentElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
item.Content = readerLoad;
```

the ContentElement does not play anymore Role here. So can change this part into this one line code:

```
item.Content = XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(serial.Element("Content").Value)));
```

With these majors changes, I've able to perform copy and paste function on my selected items.